# Complex page layout and design

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page that has a around 30 links divided among 6 groups.

```
Boat
 a
 b
 c
Horses
 d
 e

... etc
```

When the user clicks the link the page will display a series of controls (dropdown, htmltable, chart) in a layout specific only to the link that was clicked.

I have a few ideas:

1. Create separate aspx pages for each link that share the same master page (about 30 aspx pages).  Advantage: design/layout is easy.  Disadvantage: 30 aspx pages
2. Determine if any links use the the same layout and create a common page with place holder controls
3. Dynamically load controls/css etc onto the page.

So a few questions:

1. Are any of these good approaches?
2. What are some alternative approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly think twice before creating one monster page.  It can become a real maintenance nightmare.

Just because you have 30 aspx pages does not mean you have to repeat yourself.  Structure common functionality into reusable controls.  Maintenance isn't so bad.

Comment: I've decided to create 30 pages that share a common interface as well as masterpage.  This will be far less confusing and more maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Microsoft's Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax) and organize the link into tabs.  So you have a tab for Horses, and it shows all the links for horses when active etc... You can even set up the tabs programattically if you want.  All your tab layouts can be custom based on which category the user picked.

That is probably the best way, as it's very easy to setup and all works just like regular webforms controls.  The only possible issue is it might make your site javascript dependent.  I do not know how well or if the controls in the ajax control toolkit degrade when a user without javascript enabled views the page.

Comment: -1 Trying to combine 30 separate views on a single page doesn't sound like the best way.  It sounds like a real headache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to keep the launching page (page with links) as small as possible so that it loads very fast.  Combining all the tabs into one page is not an option.  The only solution where it would work on one page is if controls were loaded dynamically on click.

Comment: I never meant my answer as a complete option #4 competing with options 1,2 and 3.  Tabs can be a great way to display sub pages while still allowing controls to stay above and below the tabbed area.  You do not have to put all the views into one single aspx page in order to use tabbed data, as user controls and/or setting the controls dynamically can help.  Doing it dynamically means less initial overhead as well.

I was merely pointing out that using a tabbed layout and design (which is mentioned in the title and post itself) can be very useful from a user perspective.

Comment: Yes, but the design I'm looking for will not change the layout of the launching page.  There are links running down the left side and the rest of the area is for controls related to the clicked link.